# Storing file on android phone

Tags: android, file

I'm a Android newbie and got problems with storing a file on the internal memory. I read the tutorial about it in the android docs and copied the code. If I'm running the app in the simulator the file is created and everything is fine, but if I run it on a real phone I can't find the file?! As I use `openFileOutput()` it should be saved in the folder of the app in Android/data/myApp/... , but actually this folder for my app does not exist... :/

Can anybody help me?

Here is my code:

```
    String FILENAME = "hello_file";
    String string = "hello world!";

    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(string.getBytes());
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Did you include this to your manifest file :  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` ?

Comment: I got <code>  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> </code> since I only write to internal memory

Comment: oh noooo, now I see, I messed something up. Of course Access_fine location is something totally different! Thanks for your comment! now it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The data folder is invisible for all users, except the user account your app is running in. You will need root permissions to view the contents of this folder.

For testing purposes you can save it as MODE_READ_WORLD (or something) then you should be able to see it. However it's advised to restore it back to MODE_PRIVATE when publishing your app.

Comment: oh sorry, that was a copy paste mistake. It does not work for me with <code> MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE </code> either...

Comment: You can't see your app's folder in the /data directory but you can still change into it with cd command.

Comment: That doesn't work yet either. Actually I should be more precise: When I run the app in the virtual simulator everything is fine and the file is created and I can see it... If I run the app on my phone with usb-debugging mode I cannot even see the file in the file explorer of eclipse while running the app, at least there I should see it right?

Comment: ahmmm... maybe you should try MODE_WORLD_READABLE. With MODE_WORD_WRITEABLE you still don't have read access I think.

Apropos: on the emulator you have root by default. You can recognize this as the command prompt starts with a # sign. On your phone without root you have a $ sign. That's why you see it in emulator but not on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

In the real phone you cannot access the data folder. only if the phone is rooted you can access the data folder but you can check in the emulator whether the file is created or not

Comment: So I can't access files through a file explorer which my app has created with the mode world-writeable? My situtation is that I want to record some data on my phone, save it to a file and then copy it to my pc...